# GWT - Is it possible to create new HTML elements (from the server) or i can just to update the ones loaded on the client?

Tags: gwt

Im new about this technology, but I would like to know if is possible to create new object (html elements, such div/span/and so on...) dinamically on server and send it to the client, or if i can just load the ones made on client-side when i develop it in the application.

I don't ask how to do it (i think its a delicate argument), but if I can, and (if yes) where i can get some stuff/example/tutorial to do this.

**Example**

What i usually do :

```
...
public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
    if(result) {
        myFunction();
    }
}

...

myFunction() {
    InlineLabel label=new  InlineLabel();
    this.add(label)    
}
```

What im looking for :

```
...
public void onSuccess(InlineLabel result) {
    this.add(result) 
}
```

So, i don't need to load in advance the Object, but load them only if i click on some button (or if i perform an action). This will save a lot of code (that is inutil, if i don't do any action) loaded (as JavaScript) on the client.

As usual, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but please feel free to amend your question or post a comment if I've missed the mark.

## The host page

A GWT app is loaded in the following (simplified) process:

- A host page (HTML) is loaded
- A bootstrapping script is loaded
- A compiled app script is loaded

The host page can contain any HTML you want. The only requirement is that you include a `<script>` element that loads the GWT bootstrapping script.

As a result, you can have the server return a page that contains any server-generated markup you like.

## Server-rendered HTML at runtime

Once your app is running, you can send off asynchronous requests in your code to retrieve arbitrary data from the server. One option is to retrieve server-generated HTML and insert it into your application.

For this option, you'll want to instantiate an [`HTML` widget](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html), then use its `setHTML` method to insert the server-generated markup into the widget.

## Client-generated

As an alternative, you can retrieve structured data from the server via GWT RPC. Objects created on a Java-based server are serialised by GWT on the server and deserialised on the client back into regular objects. You can then pull data out of these objects using accessor methods (`getName`, `getId`, etc.). At this point, you have several options:

- Generate some HTML using `StringBuilder` and the like, then use `setHTML` on an `HTML` widget.
- Generate DOM elements with the [`DOM` class](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html)
- Set the data into widgets and add them to panels or the root panel.

Comment: Uhm...your explanation looks interessant. But this is the standard "write HTML and post it". I mean to manipulate GTW Widget UI and send it (after the GWT transformation), like a InlayLabel() (span), FlowPanel (div), Image() (<img>). Is it possible? Or i can just send it the "html written by myself" server side?

Comment: Ah its possible :) Can you give to me a small example of this? (For example, add a new InlayLabel() from server, after an asynch call, that will be added when the onSuccess function is loaded on client-side)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm mistaken. Anything that needs to be sent across GWT RPC needs to implement `IsSerializable`, and many widgets are not. Look for classes that implement `IsSerializable` or `Serializable` to determine if they can be sent from the server. In this case, I would recommend that you consider creating some serializable class with all the information needed to create the widget on the client, then load create this widget on the client and add it there instead. http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideSerializableTypes

Comment: Uhm...so is not possible to do what i need. IMO this will be a big limitation of the framework, isnt it? Looks strange to load ALL elements on the clients when (maybe) i don't need them at all in some moments...

Comment: When you don't need a widget to be shown on the page, you don't need to add it to the page (that is, don't add it to any widgets that are already shown on the page). This is the "usual" way that web apps are built - only the data is transferred over the wire. For example, when I write an app using JQuery, my requests to the server return JSON data that I then load into a table or into elements as required. Take a look at the RPC examples on the GWT docs for an example of how GWT RPC is intended to be used.

Comment: Uhm yes, with JQuery you can do it. But with GWT its looks different. I saw the docs, but as i said, it loads all widgets on the client. Than, after some asynch call to the server, it load/unload them on the client. But maybe i have to see different docs. Example : take a look at http://www.netbeans.com/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-gwt.html , on Creating an AJAX Random Quote Generator. Yes, the return string is loaded dinamically, but i mean "load GWT UI object". Thats different. If you have a good tutorial to "how to do it", let me know! Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I've added an example. Maybe this will make more clear my request :)

Comment: In the example, `GWTServiceUsageExample` is a `VerticalPanel`, which is a widget. This widget is created on the client side (when `new GWTServiceUsageExample()` is called). Inside this `VerticalPanel`, the `lblServerReply` is a `Label` that is also created on the client with the `new` keyword. The `GWTService` that is called only gets a String from the server, and it sets the label's text to be that String. This is probably the right way to go. As an alternative, create and add the `Label` widget once you've received a response from the server. (That is, use `new Label(result)` in `onSuccess`)

Answer (score 2):

GWT does not support the pattern you showed, but you can achieve a similar effect with "code splitting": read http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html

With code splitting, the client only downloads the script it needs right away (configured by the developer).  If, for example, the user navigates to a more complex area of the UI that requires more widgets, additional code will be downloaded.

Comment: Uhm...nice solution :) This will safe the download of a huge lines of inutil code :) I read the articles, but is not clear what it means as "limitations" (Iframe linker?)

Comment: If you're using the default linker you won't have a problem.

Comment: But it refeers to the main Java linker (the one who manage libraries/etc etc)?

Comment: It's referring to the GWT linker that turns your Java code into JavaScript.  If you aren't sure which linker you're using, you'll be fine - go ahead and use this method.